# Escape Trichotomy (Proposition 2.1): level set given by Green’s function

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, riemann-surfaces, greens-function

I am studying the Escape Trichotomy for Singularly Perturbed Rational Maps of Devaney et al. ([reference can be found here](http://myslu.stlawu.edu/%7Edlook/Papers/trich.pdf)). I need help understanding the existence of a level set coming from a Green’s function.

In Proposition 2.1. they want to show that if some critical value $v_\lambda$ of
$$F_\lambda(z) = z^{n} + \frac{\lambda}{z^{d}},\ \lambda\in\mathbb{C},\  n\geq2,\ d\geq1$$
lies in the immediate basin of attraction (denoted by $B$), then all of the critical points of $F_\lambda$ also lie in B. $F_\lambda$ is defined on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

In the proof, they construct a neighbourhood $N$, on which an analytic homeomorphism $\phi_\lambda$ conjugates $F_\lambda$ to $z^n$. This neighbourhood includes all the critical values.
Now they claim that there exists a level set $\gamma$ of the Green’s function associated to $\phi_\lambda$ which bounds a simply connected open set containing $N$.

The problem is that I am not familiar with Green's function, and therefore, I do not understand this step. So why there exists this level set $\gamma$? After that, the proof is clear to me.

Comment: It is immediate once you decode what is being done here.  Recall the Green's function associated to a Riemann map $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{D}$ is $G(z,w)=-\log\left\lvert\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{1-\overline{f(w)}f(z)}\right\rvert$, in other words, the hyperbolic distance function by pulling back along $f$.  So essentially you have a small hyperbolic circle bounding a hyperbolic disc, which is simply connected.

Comment: so the level set, they are referring to in the article, is given by the (hyperbolic) radius of the disk $\mathbb{D}$ on which $z^n$ is conjugated to $F_\lambda$?